# Can't insert a record because of "malformed record literal"

Tags: postgresql, types, visibility

The following problem has me stumped

```
SELECT string_agg(e.enumlabel, '|') as enum_value
FROM pg_type t 
   JOIN pg_enum e on t.oid = e.enumtypid  
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace 
WHERE typname = 'contacts'

above|below|lateral|lateral-bottom|lateral-top|within

CREATE TABLE unit_contacts
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('unit_contacts_id_seq1'::regclass),
  unit_id integer NOT NULL,
  old_contact contacts NOT NULL,
  contact contacts NOT NULL,
  old_with_unit integer NOT NULL,
  with_unit integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT unit_contacts__pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

mm=> INSERT INTO unit_contacts VALUES (15, 1, 'below', 'below', 8112, 2);
ERROR:  malformed record literal: "below"
LINE 1: ...SERT INTO unit_contacts VALUES (15, 1, 'below', '...
```

I can't figure out why I am unable to insert the row at all.

Comment: I am not all that familiar with PostgreSQL, but I don't think "contacts" is a data type...Is it a custom data type? If it is, what is the definition of the custom "contacts" data type?

Comment: Works fine for me. What happens if you specify the columns (which you should **always** do anyway, **always**, no exceptions ever) in your insert: `insert into unit_contacts (id, unit_id, old_contact, ...) values (...)`?

Comment: @muistooshort you can build the schema? what is the deal with the contacts data type?

Comment: @gangreen: PostgreSQL has a rather rich type system that allows you to define all sorts of custom data types: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-enum.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype.html

Comment: What version of postgresql are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously a naming conflict.

The error message for a missing enum value would be:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input value for enum rainbow: "below"
> LINE 1: INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'below');
> ```

Your error message reveals that a composite type of the same name exists, most likely from a table of the same name. **Avoid using identical names!**

To reproduce, consider this demo:

```sql
CREATE TYPE contacts  AS ENUM ('above', 'below', 'lateral');
SELECT 'above'::contacts;  -- all good, before the next step

CREATE TEMP TABLE contacts (id int, x text); -- !the crucial part

SELECT string_agg(e.enumlabel, '|') as enum_value
FROM   pg_type t 
JOIN   pg_enum e on t.oid = e.enumtypid  
WHERE  t.typname = 'contacts'; -- all good

CREATE TEMP TABLE t (id int, r contacts);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'above');  -- ERROR
SELECT 'above'::contacts;  -- same ERROR
```

This can only happen if enum type and table (the row type) exist in **two different schemas**. PostgreSQL would not allow both in the same schema. In your case, the table's schema was listed before the enum's schema in the [**search_path**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) when you created the table. Or maybe the enum type did not even exist at the time. See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

In my example the temporary table comes first because the schema `pg_temp` comes first in the search path by default. When I create the table, "contacts" is resolved to the row type (`pg_temp.contacts`), not the enum type (`public.contacts`).

If you **must** have a table and an enum of the same name, be sure to **schema-qualify the type-names** in use. In my example:

```
pg_temp.contacts -- the composite type
public.contacts  -- the enum type
```

Comment: Erwin... you should hold a Pg bootcamp, and I will come attend it. Yes, you were correct. I had a table called 'contacts' tucked away in one of my schemas. What a mess. Many thanks. I can now go fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this error in a different situation where I had a **composite type that only had 1 property**. It worked if **I added another property to the composite type**. For example:

```
drop type if exists mything;
drop type if exists mything2;
create type mything as (val varchar(200));
create type mything2 as (val varchar(200), wat int);

-- Works
select val from unnest(array[('ok',null),('doke',null)]::mything2[]);

-- ERROR:  Missing left parenthesis.malformed record literal: "ok"
select value from unnest(array[('ok'),('doke')]::mything[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding an answer because I faced a similar issue, as mentioned by @JohnnyFun.
I had a composite type with a single property and got the "malformed record literal" error when trying to run the following select statement:

```
select array[('my value 1'), ('my value 2')]::mytype[];
```

By reading the official documents, I found [this article](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-IO-SYNTAX) explaining different ways to write a composite type.
We have the literal constant way, in which we use single quotes:

```
select array['("my value 1")','("my value 2")']::mytype[];
```

And we have the row expression way, in which we use the "row" keyword before the parenthesis:

```
select array[row('my value 1'), row('my value 2')]::mytype[];
```

However the "row" keyword it's optional when the composite type has more than one field, like:

```
select array[('my value 1', 10), ('my value 2', 50)]::mytype2[];
```

In summary, the malformed error mentioned by @JohnnyFun happened because when you use the row expression syntax to write a composite type, you need to explictly add the "row" keyword (row('my value')) when the composite type has one field. Otherwise, it's optional when it has more than one field.

I hope it may be helpful to someone else.